# "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error" when inserting CSV file to database in Symfony2

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, csv, mariadb

I've written a script that allows a client to upload a CSV file of data which will then be entered in to the database. The script uploads the CSV file to the server first, and then the second part of the script reads the CSV file and then goes to enter that information in to the database.

However, when the CSV data is being inserted in to the database I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'UK,Managed,Company UK Glasgow,Glasgow,G1 G1
>   1AA,3723,Completed,Scheduled,2014-03' at line 1

Here is the CSV data:

```
account_number,customer_reference,billing_customer,division,customer_site,town,postcode,job_number,job_status,job_type,completion_date,description,waste_type,ewc_code,container,quantity,total_uom,co2_saving,total_resource,total_co2_saving,recovery_rate,disposal_method,waste_hierarchy,customer_order_date,job_notes,customer_ref_po,uploaded,processed,deleted
1,633,Company UK,Managed,Company UK Glasgow,Glasgow,G1 G1 1AA,3723,Completed,Scheduled,2014-03-24,24/05/2014 - General Waste,General Waste to Energy,20 03 01,Wheelie Bin 1100 Litre,4,320,0.84,0,0.03,0,Transfer Station,Incinerator,2014-05-27,,0,2014-08-05,1,0
```

Here is the Controller with the upload and CSV insert script:
        $fileUpload = $this->createForm(new FileuploadType());

```
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $fileUpload->bind($request);

        $dir = '/var/www/cwwa/web/uploads/csv/';

        if($fileUpload->isValid()) {
            $file2 = $fileUpload['attachment']->getData();
            $file2->move($dir, $file2->getClientOriginalName());

            $fileName = $file2->getClientOriginalName();

            $uploadedFile = basename($dir.''.$file2->getClientOriginalName());

            $recordData = array();
            $table = 'enviro_figures_upload';

            if (($file = fopen($dir.$fileName, "r")) !== FALSE) {

                $row = 0;

                while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    if ($row == 0) {
                        $fieldNames = $data;
                        $row++;
                    } else {
                        $recordData[] = $data;
                        $row++;
                    }
                }

            }

            $fields = implode(',', $fieldNames);

            foreach ($recordData as $record) {
                $values = implode(',',$record);

                $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($values);";

            }

            $rsm = new ResultSetMapping($dm);
            $insert = $dm->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

            $result = $insert->getResult();

        }
    }
```

I've added quotation marks to the data and the error still occurs.

**EDIT**
I've changed this line:

```
$values = implode(',',$record);
```

To this:

```
$values = '"'.implode(',',$record).'"';
```

This adds quotation to the values being added, but this has results in quotations on either side of the value string. See below:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO enviro_figures_upload (account_number,customer_reference,billing_customer,division,customer_site,town,postcode,job_number,job_status,job_type,completion_date,description,waste_type,ewc_code,container,quantity,total_uom,co2_saving,total_resource,total_co2_saving,recovery_rate,disposal_method,waste_hierarchy,customer_order_date,job_notes,customer_ref_po,uploaded,processed,deleted) VALUES (1,633,Company UK,Managed,Company UK Glasgow,Glasgow,G1 G1 1AA,3723,Completed,Scheduled,2014-03-24,24/05/2014 - General Waste,General Waste to Energy,20 03 01,Wheelie Bin 1100 Litre,4,320,0.84,0,0.03,0,Transfer Station,Incinerator,2014-05-27,,0,2014-08-05,1,0);':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UK,Managed,Company UK Glasgow,Glasgow,G1 G1 1AA,3723,Completed,Scheduled,2014-03' at line 1
```

**EDIT 2**
Following on from VMai's comment which suggested this:

```
$values = '"' . implode('","',$record) . '"';
```

This solved the SQLSTATE issue. However, it has thrown up a new issue:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

I've checked the database and the Query does insert one row of data, no matter how many rows are in the CSV file. Refreshing the page then inserts the same row of data to the database.

Comment: The single quotes at the start and at the end are still missing: `$values = "'". implode(',',$record) . ".";` should do this. But this is not a robust solution. What if one of the fields contains a single quote or some such?

Comment: Well as you say that some of the actual data does contain single quotes. I suppose I could invert it, do `'"'`. I'll try this.

Comment: Assuming Doctrine as ORM, I would recommend using a prepared statement instead, have a look at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#using-prepared-statements. Some values will have double quotes too for sure ...

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your first comment.

Comment: I wasn't observing enough :-( You've got to be consistent with your quotes and quote every field of the csv file: It should be `$values = '"' . implode('","',$record) . '"';` to get all values proper quoted with double quotes. Hopefully there aren't ones in your values like `19" rack` or so ...

Answer (score 0):

You've got to execute your INSERT for each record:

So it should be

```
// I assume we need only one of this
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping($dm);

foreach ($recordData as $record) {
    $values = '"'. implode('","',$record) . '"';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($values);";

    $insert = $dm->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    $result = $insert->getResult();
}
```

instead.

**Remark**

I would recommend the use of a prepared statement. Prepare it once before the loop and execute it with binding of the input values inside the loop for every record.

Answer (score -2):

Symfony 2.3

I suggest use object (flush) , but if you use sql without entity, Try this

```
foreach ($recordData as $record) {

    $values = '"'. implode('","',$record) . '"';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($values);";
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $em->execute();
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.